# BigQuery's Data Transfer Service

Tags: google-bigquery

Can Google BigQuery's Data Transfer Service use multiple cloud storage location as source destination for Data-Ingestion into BigQuery ?

Is there any different in the way BQ charges data ingestion from GCS vs Any other Cloud source ?

It is mentioned on Data transfer Service's documentation that Effective from 1-June-2017, BQ will charge monthly subscriptions for Data-Transfer-Service ? Do we have any detail on cost model ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm an engineer on the BQ Data Transfer team.

With the data transfer service, you can create multiple transfer configs. For example, you can connect to 100 different GCS buckets that back different DCM accounts (for example), if you like.

There is no difference for loading data - the load jobs in BQ are still free.

The data transfer service will indeed follow a subscription model soon. For details, you can contact Sales, or you may wait for more documentation on https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/transfer/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks....Is there any documentation on speeding up ingestion from GCS to BQ using DataTransferService ? I have 500 csv files(each with 25 GB uncompressed size) to be ingested into BQ. I am hoping to have a parallel ingestion into BQ daily partition....Out of curiosity, Can i use BQ's UDF (user defined functions) for such ingestion process? Is there any cost associated with UDF approach ?

Comment: Hi Bhavik, the data transfer service only connects to specific services (e.g. DoubleClick, YouTube). It does not provide general GCS functionality at this time. For loading from GCS, feel free to simply start multiple GCS load jobs. Loads will be the fastest if the files are not compressed and if you set quoted newlines to false, because this allows the most parallelization.